# ¿Cómo se puede utilizar la impresora Microsoft Print to PDF en Java?

Tags: java, maven

Estoy trabajando en Java con Maven e hice un proyecto en donde modifico un archivo excel (allí le agrego una imagen en una celda combinada, le agrego una fila y le quito la cuadrícula, por último guardo los cambios en el archivo.

En el pom uso las dependencias que mediante consultas ayudan a esto y son:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Aún no he logrado el 100% del objetivo (ya tengo una función para realizar las modificaciones del excel y me hace falta concluir la función que convertirá el contenido de la hoja de trabajo (si se activa los bordes de impresión el contenido alcanza en un A4 de forma vertical y aparte le quiero poner los márgenes estrechos a la impresión), este es el código que tengo actualmente para la conversión:

```
public static void aPDF(String pathExcel) {
        try {
            String pathPDF = pathExcel.replace("xlsx", "pdf");
             FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(pathExcel);
             Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);            
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Hoja1");
            PDDocument docPDF = new PDDocument();
            PDPage pagPDF = new PDPage();
            docPDF.addPage(pagPDF);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(docPDF, pagPDF);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Es mejor insertar la imagen directamente en el documento PDF o lo dejo en la función que modifica el excel?

Comment: ¿Qué sería "mejor" para ti?: Mas fácil, mas mantenible, mas rápido, etc.

Comment: para mi sería pasar el documento a pdf sin la imagen y después agregarsela al pdf solo que también estoy teniendo errores con ello aunque tengo la imagen en la carpeta de recursos (no se encuentran los archivos del proyecto; .java, .xml y otros)